# Rcpp and custom header includes

Tags: include, rcpp

I have made an R package using Rcpp and would like to include a header and a cpp file to my cpp function.
I placed it in the src file, next to my function-cpp file. Now I include it with #include "header.h"
But the compiler fails to include it. Only when I provide the absolut path to the file it works.
I tested with path's without empty spaces and I changed the windows backslash to forward slash but still no luck.
When going to the online help's I have found nothing that helps me ..
Can you tell me what to do?
Including standard header file via <> works fine ..

Comment: This is not a _minimally reproducible example_.  Also, several of my packages use a header file in the `src/` directory without any extra settings.

Comment: Well I can upload my whole package if that helps ..? Posting the files here will help nothing as they are way too big .. Also I read that you should not use Rcpp::sourceCpp() in a Rcpp package? But how do I compile the code then and export the function I need to R?

Comment: Using the compileAttributes() is the right way? Then how do I use this together with c++11. Specifying // [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]] is not enogh ..

Comment: There are many existing tutorials about how to create a package using Rcpp. Try one of those. There are also 1200+ example packages on CRAN.